# JavaFX styles lost when loading an external Jar(plugin architecture)

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to create a JavaFX application that can work with plugins, those plugins are other jars loaded on runtime and openened to look for the implementation of an specific interface I created, I'm able to load the jar and to find the specific class but some styles that the loaded jar can't be loaded, let me explain what I did:

I created three maven projects, these projects are the following:

**Core**: Has an interface the the plugin should implement(TestPlugin.java), and a interface that the main program should implement(TestSceneHandler.java)

TestPlugin.java

```
public interface TestPlugin {

    void init(TestSceneHandler sceneHandler);

}
```

TestSceneHandler.java

```
import javafx.scene.Parent;

public interface TestSceneHandler {

    void setView(Parent node);

}
```

**Plugin**: Has the **Core** as a dependency and a class that implements TestPlugin.java, I left the Main.java so it can work on both modes, sigle app and plugin but it's not really necsessary

MyTestViewController.java

```
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyTestViewController extends GridPane {

    public MyTestViewController() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/pluginView.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

}
```

TestPluginImpl.java

```
package sample;

public class TestPluginImpl implements TestPlugin {
    @Override
    public void init(TestSceneHandler testSceneHandler) {
        testSceneHandler.setView(new MyTestViewController());
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new MyTestViewController(), 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

pluginView.fxml

```xml
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<fx:root  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
          type="javafx.scene.layout.GridPane"
          alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" stylesheets="style.css">
    <Label>
        Hello world
    </Label>
</fx:root>
```

style.css

```css
.root {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

**App**: Has the **Core** as a dependency and a class that implements TestSceneHandler.java

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new TestScene(), 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

sample.fxml

```xml
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<fx:root xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
     type="javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane">

    <top>
        <HBox style="-fx-background-color: orange;">
            <children>
                <Label>
                    This is the header
                </Label>
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </top>

</fx:root>
```

TestScene.java

```
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public class TestScene extends BorderPane implements TestSceneHandler {

    private static final String ROOT_FOLDER = "Zamba";
    private static final String PLUGIN_FOLDER = "plugins";
    private static final String USER_HOME = System.getProperty("user.home");

    public TestScene() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }

        File pluginFolder = initFolder();
        readPlugins(pluginFolder);
    }

    private File initFolder() {
        final String ROOT_FOLDER_PATH = USER_HOME + "/" + ROOT_FOLDER;
        final String PLUGIN_FOLDER_PATH = ROOT_FOLDER_PATH + "/" + PLUGIN_FOLDER;

        File appFolder = new File(ROOT_FOLDER_PATH);

        if(!appFolder.exists()) {
            appFolder.mkdir();
        }

        File pluginFolder = new File(PLUGIN_FOLDER_PATH);

        if(!pluginFolder.exists()) {
            pluginFolder.mkdir();
        }

        return pluginFolder;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether a file is a JAR File.
     */
    public static boolean isJarFile(File file) throws IOException {
        if (!isZipFile(file)) {
            return false;
        }
        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);
        boolean manifest = zip.getEntry("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF") != null;
        zip.close();
        return manifest;
    }
    /**
     * Determine whether a file is a ZIP File.
     */
    public static boolean isZipFile(File file) throws IOException {
        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            return false;
        }
        if(!file.canRead()) {
            throw new IOException("Cannot read file "+file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        if(file.length() < 4) {
            return false;
        }
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
        int test = in.readInt();
        in.close();
        return test == 0x504b0304;
    }

    private void readPlugins(File pluginFolder) {
        File[] pluginFolderFiles = pluginFolder.listFiles();
        Arrays.asList(pluginFolderFiles).forEach(file -> {
            System.out.println("Filee: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

            try {
                if(isJarFile(file)) {
                    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(file);

                    Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries();

                    URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + file.getAbsolutePath()+"!/") };
                    URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

                    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                        JarEntry je = e.nextElement();

                        if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")){
                            continue;
                        }

                        // -6 because of .class
                        String className = je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6);
                        className = className.replace('/', '.');

                        Class c = cl.loadClass(className);

                        if(TestPlugin.class.isAssignableFrom(c) && c != TestPlugin.class) {
                            System.out.println("Plugin found!!!");

                            TestPlugin plugin = (TestPlugin)c.newInstance();
                            plugin.init(this);
                        }

                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setView(Parent parent) {
        setCenter(parent);
    }
}
```

---

When executing the project **Plugin** as an standalone app this is the result:

[image: Correct styles]

But when it is executed through the **App** project the result is the following:

[image: Invalid styles]

As you can see the styles are gone and I have an error on the console:

```
Plugin found!!!
dic 30, 2018 5:41:30 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "style.css" not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by a classpath issue since you are creating your own `ClassLoader` to load your plugins. The value of the `stylesheet` attribute in your FXML is `style.css`. This is the same as doing:

```
GridPane pane = new GridPane();
pane.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
```

Which will look for a resource named `style.css` relative to the root of the classpath. This is because there is no scheme; see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getStylesheets()) for details. The problem is this behavior uses the `ClassLoader` for the JavaFX classes to load the resource. Unfortunately, your resource is not visible to that `ClassLoader` but rather the `ClassLoader` you created to load the plugin.

The fix for this is to provide the full URL for the CSS resource file. This is done by using `@` (see [Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#location_resolution)). When using `@` the location is relative to the FXML file. For example, if your FXML file is `/fxml/PluginView.fxml` and your CSS file is `/styles/style.css`, you'd have:

```xml
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<fx:root  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
          type="javafx.scene.layout.GridPane"
          alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" stylesheets="@../styles/style.css">
    <Label>
        Hello world
    </Label>
</fx:root>
```

This will call `getStylesheets().add(...)` with something like:

```
jar:file:///path/to/plugin/file.jar!/styles/style.css
```

Which can be located regardless of the `ClassLoader` used.

---

Another likely issue is in your `style.css` file. You use `.root {}` but the `root` style-class is only automatically added to roots of a `Scene`. What you probably want to do is set your own style-class and use *that* in the CSS file.

---

Also, you are writing your own plugin-discovery-and-load code. Not saying you can't keep doing what you're doing but I just want to let you know you don't have to reinvent the wheel. Java has [`java.util.ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) for exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I did what you suggested, now the attribute on the fxml looks like stylesheets="@style.css", but I'm still getting the error with the correct path: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged WARNING: Resource "jar:file:C:\Users\josegum\Zamba\plugins\Plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/style.css" not found.

As you can see the slashes are like this: \ not like this: /. If through code I load the file with the correct slashes everithing works fine, ex: getStylesheets().add("jar:file:C:/Users/josegum/Zamba/plugins/Plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/style.css");, any solution?

Comment: I downloaded your project and it worked, I changed the way of loading jar to the ServiceLoader like you and now everything works as expected, thanks a lot bro, you're the man